# How to remove white box from TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, androidx, android-textinputlayout

Today I have just updated my `dependencies` of `material design`

from `1.0.0` to `1.1.0-alpha09`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

Now i"m getting strange issue in `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`

Here is my Code

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailTextInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

after updating the dependencies I'm getting boxed design in my `TextInputLayout`

Output of above code

[image]

if i use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` I'm getting expected result

[image]

Can anybody help me to solve this issue

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

> I have already tried  `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` them I'm getting this

[image: output] ,

> if i use `app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"` then getting this

[image: output]

## SOLVED

No need to use **`boxBackgroundMode`**

You need to add **`@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout`** in your `TextInputLayout`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/emailTextInputEditText"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Use `boxBackgroundMode` to get rid of the issue, default is **filled**.

Comment: @JeelVankhede thanks fro the replay if i have already tried  `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` them I'm getting this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MNyM.png) , if i use `app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"` then getting this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RClPT.png)

Comment: Okay, can you try with this as parent style also? `@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout`

Comment: @JeelVankhede thanks it works can you please post that as answer so it can help others in future

Comment: It is the standard behaviour. You can achieve something similar using a filled style with `<item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/black</item>`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti tthanks but why it not required to add `@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout ` in version`1.0.0`

Comment: @Goku It is not a good choice to use `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout` and not `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can you please explain more, if possible post as answer in brief so it can help me as well others also

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout` is already parent of `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*` *(If you check source)* unless API changes. For now we're good to go.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Exactly. And using that parent you will lose a lot of material attribute like shape and materialThemeOverlay

Comment: @Goku just done

Comment: The only valid solution, thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To revert back to old style with no filed background but only bottom border, one should use following style:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
           ...
           style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
           ....
           >
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Using theme **`Widget.Design.TextInputLayout`** will generate expected output like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using a [material Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) the default style used by the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) is `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox`

[image]

To obtain something similar just change the background color using the `boxBackgroundColor` attribute:

```
  <style name="CustomFilledBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@myColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Also use the `android:hint="@string/hint_enter_email"` in the `TextInputLayout` not in the `TextInputEditText`

Comment: Thanks i'm using `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"` but getting this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPYEy.png)

Comment: And my app this `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: Use the same color of your app background, black in your case.

Comment: Sir, i have already tried that check this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJZlZ.png)

Comment: @Goku Something strange in your style. You should use boxBackgroundColor with a dark color and hint text white or red.

Answer (score 1):

For me using @style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout produced undesirable formatting results, specifically alignment issues with the editText box.

I used `boxBackgroundMode` set to none for awhile, and after updating material design in my project the error icon mentioned started showing. May be a bug (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122445449).

For now I'm still setting the `boxBackgroundMode` to none, and hiding the error icon by setting the color to transparent. This way I keep the material design.

```
app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
app:errorIconTint="@android:color/transparent"



<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
        app:errorIconTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/message_ellipsis"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your TextInputLayout:

```
app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
```

Probably you have set boxBackgroundMode to filled or maybe it's set by default. Just add above line, and this should fix the issue.

Comment: Change your TextInputLayout. More details https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior with `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0`

Applying transparent background to `TextInputEditText` does the tricks.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```